# join 2 pandas dataframes with different number of columns

Tags: python, pandas

Consider we have 2 dataframes:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['a','b','c']) ##empty
d = {'a': [1, 2], 'b': [3, 4]} 
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

How can I join them in order the result to be this:

```
a b c
-----
1 3 Nan
---------
2 4 Nan
-------
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) by columns from `df`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['a','b','c']) 
d = {'a': [1, 2], 'b': [3, 4]} 
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d).reindex(columns=df.columns)
print (df1)
   a  b   c
0  1  3 NaN
1  2  4 NaN
```

Difference betwen soluions - if columns are not sorted get different output:

```
#different order
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['c','a','b']) 
d = {'a': [1, 2], 'b': [3, 4]} 
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

print (df1.reindex(columns=df.columns))
    c  a  b
0 NaN  1  3
1 NaN  2  4

print (df1.merge(df,how='left'))
   a  b    c
0  1  3  NaN
1  2  4  NaN
```

Comment: ah you beat me to it !

Answer (score 2):

> > How can I join them

If you have the dataframe existing somewhere(not creating a new), do :

```
df1.merge(df,how='left')

   a  b    c
0  1  3  NaN
1  2  4  NaN
```

**Note:** This produces sorted columns. So if order of columns are already sorted, this will work fine , else not.

Comment: I think not, because `merge` sorting output columns, test `df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['c','a','b'])`

Comment: I think if change order of columns in df like `df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['c','a','b'])` it not change order of columns in final df1.

Comment: Yes, output remains same i guess.

Comment: ohh now i got your point. :) but if there is a dataframe already created, i think this is best.. no?

Comment: I think it is only good add to answer - merge sorting, so if not already sorted columns in both get different order. It should be problem, but if sorting columns then not.

Comment: @iamklaus yes, but again, gives sorted column output. :) so depends what OP needs.